# Unable to get javascript to work in hiding div tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code to hide a particular div tag and show another when a button is clicked. And for some reason I am not able to get it to work. Any suggestions as what may be wrong?

```
        <div class="profile" align="center">
             <form action="register"><br>
                 <p>Welcome #lastname , #firstname </p>

                   <div id="readonly" class="input2" style="display:inline">
                   ………code here …        
                   </div>

                   <div id="editable" class="input2" style="display:none">     
                          …… code here ….
                   </div>

                   <div id="editable" class="reginput" style="display:none" >     
                  …… code here ….   
                   </div>

                   <div align="center">
                       <input type="button" class="buttoncls" value="Edit" id="btnchange" onclick="hideandshow();" /> 
                   </div><br>
                   <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        function hideandshow(){
                                        if(document.getElementById(readonly).style.display = "none"){
                                document.getElementById(editable).style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById(readonly).style.display = "inline";
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById(editable).style.display = "inline";
                                document.getElementById(readonly).style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
            </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the ids with quotes. Like:

```
document.getElementById('readonly')
                      //^--------^--------------- see the quotes?
```

`getElementById` expects the id to be in `string`.

Also, ids have to be unique, which in your html is definitely not. Use classes instead.

And, your `if` condition is using assignment operator `=`. Instead use `==`

Comment: I have tried with unique ids earlier. It did not work. I have used it before even when the ids were not unique and it worked. No idea what the problem is now.

Comment: That was the error. Thanks a ton! my screen wasnt showing me the whole page (I didnt align it well, my bad!).

Comment: @user3335993, glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
Have a very good look in your if condition you have to use logial operator (==)  not (=)
and     document.getElementById("editable") is another issue.

```
<div class="profile" align="center">
                 <form action="register"><br>
                     <p>Welcome #lastname , #firstname </p>

                       <div id="readonly" class="input2" style="display:inline">
                       ………code here …        
                       </div>

                       <div id="editable" class="input2" style="display:none">     
                              …… code here ….
                       </div>

                       <div id="Div1" class="reginput" style="display:none" >     
                      …… code here ….   
                       </div>

                       <div align="center">
                           <input type="button" class="buttoncls" value="Edit" id="btnchange" onclick="hideandshow();" /> 
                       </div><br>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                           function hideandshow() {
                               if (document.getElementById('readonly').style.display == "none") {
                                   document.getElementById('editable').style.display = "none";
                                   document.getElementById('readonly').style.display = "inline";
                               } else {
                                   document.getElementById('editable').style.display = "inline";
                                   document.getElementById('readonly').style.display = "none";
                               }
                           }
                        </script>
                </form>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideandshow(){
if(document.getElementById("readonly").style.display == "none"){
document.getElementById("editable").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("readonly").style.display = "inline";
} else {
document.getElementById("editable").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("readonly").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written some code, but seems like you don't know javascript, the mistake you did is whenever you want to get element by using id you have to pass id as string but here you have written directly. i.e. javascript parser and engine will treats that as a variable, in this place all are undefined na, that is the main problem.So write

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                        function hideandshow(){
                                        if(document.getElementById("readonly").style.display = "none"){
                                document.getElementById("editable").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("readonly").style.display = "inline";
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("editable").style.display = "inline";
                                document.getElementById("readonly").style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```